# how to release the memory of a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

We can do it on unique pointer. But how to do it on shared pointer? If I do reset, the memory is deleted.

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(10));
int* q = p.release(); //???
```

Comment: You can't release the memory unless the reference count is 1. The best you can hope for is reducing the reference count.

Comment: `p = nullptr`, or `p = NULL`, or `p = {}`, or `p.reset()`. But this won't release the underlying _memory_ if there are other references to it.

Comment: @juanchopanza If the count is 1. How to release the memory?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it, because there can be other `shared_ptr<int>` objects referring to the same `int`.